# Change the visibility of a function in a Derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm tryinh to force people deriving a class to reimplement a function foo(), but still proposing a default version which have to be called explicitly. The point is to avoid code duplication of defalut version of foo() without let it be inherited "implicitly".

The common way to do it is to make a pure virtual public foo(), then a protected foo_impl(); and to call foo_impl() into foo() reimplementation:

```
class Airplane {
public:
    virtual ~Airplane() {}
    virtual fly(int destination) = 0;       // function interface, public and pure virtual
protected:
    void fly_impl(int destination);         // not-virtual function implementation, declared protected
};                                          // to prevent people calling
                                            // Derived.Airplane::fly_impl();

void Airplane::fly_impl(int destination)    // Default implementation
{
    std::cout << "Flyed defaultly to " << destination << std::endl;
}

class ModelA: public Airplane {
public:
    virtual void fly(int destination)       // reimplementation of the pure virtual function fly
    {
        fly_impl(destination);              // explicit call to default implementation
    }
    virtual ~ModelA() {}
};
```

It works, but it's a bit ugly, so I tried something else, and got a problem :

It seems that the polymorphism don't work if I change the visibility of a virtual reimplemented funciton in the derived class. I can't realy understand why, is it a bug, is it just the way that C++ do it, or is it an error from me?

There the code is (the exemple come from Effective C++ with a few modifications) :

```
class Airplane {
public:
    virtual ~Airplane() {}
protected:
    virtual void fly(int destination) = 0;  // function interface, declared protected
};                                          // to preventi people from calling
                                            // Derived.Airplace::fly();

void Airplane::fly(int destination)         // Default implementation
{
    std::cout << "Flyed defaultly to " << destination << std::endl;
}

class ModelA: public Airplane {
public:
    virtual void fly(int destination)       // reimplementation of the pure virtual function fly
    {                                       // this time it is public
        Airplane::fly(destination);         // explicit call to default implementation
    }
    virtual ~ModelA() {}
};

class ModelB: public Airplane {
public:
    virtual void fly(int destination)       // another reimplementation, public again
    {
        std::cout << "Flyed ModelBly to " << destination << std::endl;
    }
    virtual ~ModelB() {}
};

int main()
{
    ModelA A1;
    ModelB B1;

    ModelA* A2 = new ModelA();
    ModelB* B2 = new ModelB();

    Airplane* A3 = new ModelA();
    Airplane* B3 = new ModelB();

    A1.fly(1);
    B1.fly(2);

    A2->fly(3);
    B2->fly(4);

    A3->fly(5);                              // ERROR: fly() is protected in Airplane
    B3->fly(6);                              // ERROR: fly() is protected in Airplane
}
```

The question is : Is it possible for a Derived class of Airplane handeled in a Airplane* to call the Derived version of fly(), **without making Airplane::fly() public** (which would be a problem in ModelB) ? Remember that the goal is to prevent end-users to call the default version in a derived class.

Comment: Changing visibility during overriding in derived class is absolute ok. If you use the Base class Airplane instantiated, then fly cannot be called for that, but when you have ModelA instantiated, fly can be called as that's public now.

Comment: "I'm trying to make the inheritance of a virtual function implemetiation explicit." -- could you explain what that means? Could you tell us what you want to achieve and why you need it? This way it will be easier to answer the question.

Comment: By changing visibility of virtual function in derived class, you don't automatically change it in a base class, it stays the same

Comment: @Andrzej: I'm tryinh to force people to reimplement fly(), this is why it is pure virtual, but still proposing a default version which have to be called explicitly. the point is to avoid code duplication of defalut version of fly() without let it be inherited "implicitly". I hope i's more understandable.

Comment: There is nothing ugly whatsoever  in your first implementation. Keep it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I  understand your problem. You require that if your derived class wants to fall back to the implementation in the base class it has to state that explicitly. consider this solution.

```
class Airplane {
public:
  virtual ~Airplane() {}
  virtual void fly(int destination) = 0; 
}; 

inline void Airplane::fly(int destination) // implement pure virtual function!
{
  std::cout << "Flyed defaultly to " << destination << std::endl;
}

class ModelA: public Airplane {
public:
  virtual void fly(int destination) { Airplane::fly(destination); }
  virtual ~ModelA() {}
};
```

The trick here is to provide the body for the pure virtual function. It is legal, and occasionally useful, in C++.

Comment: It works fine, the only problem is that ModelA.Aireplane::fly() is legal, wich is not a big deal in ModelA, but it becomes one in ModelB... (that's why I made it protected in the exemple, though)

Comment: - Why is it so that "it is not a big deal in ModelA, but a deal in ModelB"? The "default implementation" means (at least to me) that _anyone_ can use it. How is it that some can use it and some don't? Perhaps you could give us some more background. From what you have said so far, it looks like `Airplane::fly` is not a good candidate for a general default.

Comment: I feel weird to let users be able to use the default fly() when it's reimplemented in the class. Yeah it will compile and don't leak any datas, but is it realy okay ?

Comment: Ok: not accessible to "end users". This makes sense. But then, what exactly do you find "ugly" in your original solution? It is a reasonably simple way of achieving an unconventional goal.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? The second example does not compile,. this is because function `fly`is declared as `protected`. Since you call `fly` through pointer `Airplane*`, it is the visibility access in class `Airplane` that matters: not the visibility in the 'real' (dynamic) type of the object. This is how C++ works.

Answer (score 0):

Changing visibility is fine and sometimes desirable. Your problem is that you are casting your pointers to the base class which has it protected. Due to late binding of virtual functions, the complier cannot tell the actual visibility of your pointer type and overriding will not change the visibility in the base type automatically.

An alternative way would be to have an intermediate class after Airplane that makes the method public. You can then use that as you base pointer type where required.

Comment: And so the problem get back to the initial one : end users can call Intermerdiate::fly(). Thanks for the explanation of *why* it don't work in this case, though